# Setup libGDX project using MOE plugin

Tags: libgdx

How to setup the libGDX project using MOE plugin. 
If i try to select ios-moe at the setup of libGDX project then my build fails with following error.

> Generating app in
>   /Users/USERNAME/Desktop/PaxPlay/libGDXProjects/SampleGame Executing
>   '/Users/USERNAME/Desktop/PaxPlay/libGDXProjects/SampleGame/gradlew
>   clean --no-daemon' To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM
>   will be forked. Please consider using the daemon:
>   https://docs.gradle.org/2.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
>   Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring root project
>   'SampleGame'.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.intel.gradle:moeGradlePlugin:1.1.0.final-1.
>   Searched in the following locations:
>   file:/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository/com/intel/gradle/moeGradlePlugin/1.1.0.final-1/moeGradlePlugin-1.1.0.final-1.pom
>   file:/Users/USERNAME/.m2/repository/com/intel/gradle/moeGradlePlugin/1.1.0.final-1/moeGradlePlugin-1.1.0.final-1.jar
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/intel/gradle/moeGradlePlugin/1.1.0.final-1/moeGradlePlugin-1.1.0.final-1.pom
>   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/intel/gradle/moeGradlePlugin/1.1.0.final-1/moeGradlePlugin-1.1.0.final-1.jar
>   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/intel/gradle/moeGradlePlugin/1.1.0.final-1/moeGradlePlugin-1.1.0.final-1.pom
>   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/intel/gradle/moeGradlePlugin/1.1.0.final-1/moeGradlePlugin-1.1.0.final-1.jar
>   file:/Applications/Intel/multi_os_engine/gradle/com/intel/gradle/moeGradlePlugin/1.1.0.final-1/moeGradlePlugin-1.1.0.final-1.pom
>   file:/Applications/Intel/multi_os_engine/gradle/com/intel/gradle/moeGradlePlugin/1.1.0.final-1/moeGradlePlugin-1.1.0.final-1.jar
>   Required by: :SampleGame:unspecified
>   Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
>   or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 8.492 secs Done! To import in Eclipse: File -> Import ->
>   Gradle -> Gradle Project To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open ->
>   build.gradle To import to NetBeans: File -> Open Project...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem from time to time. Use the newest version of the multi os engine, which requires no local installation.

[Multi-OS Engine Release 1.1.0](https://discuss.multi-os-engine.org/t/multi-os-engine-release-1-1-0/69)

[Samples Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/multi-os-engine/moe-samples-java)